# Aurelia nested routers and router-views

Tags: aurelia

I want to have a list of courses on the screen(contrived example).  When you click a course, it expands(still showing the list of courses) into a list of students that take the course. When I click a student it must expand into a view of the students details(still showing the list of students AND the list of courses). etc.

So basically I want to have nested routers, I think?

Example, app.js

```
config.map([
        {route: "", moduleId: 'no-selection', title: 'Select'},
        {route: "course/:course-id", moduleId: 'course',    name: 'course'}
]);
```

course.js(inject the router):

```
this.router.configure(config => {
        config.map([
            {route: "course/:course-id/student/:student-id", name: "student", moduleId: "student"}
        ]);
})
```

student.html has its own router-view element

The above works, BUT when i click a top level link(a course), the content gets put in the inner router-view.  Even worse, there is now a router-view in every student that gets expanded, how do I manage this?

Basically I can't find any documentation on how to do this - the child router stuff doesn't seem to be exactly what I need?  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you've overcomplicated the task a bit. Is that really something you necessarily need routers for? From what I understand, you should rather have stacks of regular views.

Comment: I want history on the navigation and also be able to quickly switch to a different course/student etc.  If you can suggest a different way to achieve that...  I am very new to Aurelia - might be missing something obvious

Comment: You don't need to use nested routers to achieve this. A single level router can handle it pretty easily along with a couple of components. It'd take a while to explain this and is honetly beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow question. I'd highly recommend checking out Rob Eisenberg's Intermediate Aurelia course on Vimeo. It more or less builds exactly what you want. https://vimeo.com/ondemand/intermediateaurelia/

Comment: Also, remember that a page can have multiple routes that point to it, and a page can also route to itself just with different parameters. I'll give a few hints in an answer.

Comment: I need to do an intermediate course for something as simple as this?!?

Comment: Well, this isn't a beginner concept given how you're trying to approach it. Also, just a tip: we're all here at So to help each other. You're going to have people be more receptive to helping you if you stop having a bad attitude regarding the tools you're using. Frankly, I almost deleted my answer this morning after reading your response calling the router "simplistic." Being antagonistic isn't going to make people want to help you.

Comment: Hey Ashley, I'm sorry if I came over as being antagonistic.  I just had a misconception about what the router can do - I was quite excited about having a router manage everything, and was quite disappointed when I found it doesn't quite do what I thought.  Aurelia is still cool :)  Also, I said the router is basic, not simplistic. There is nothing wrong with it being basic - basic building blocks are good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at this and how we can implement this with a single router. Here is the route structure I might use.

```
[
  { route: "", moduleId: 'no-selection', title: 'Select'},
  { route: "course/:courseId/:studentId?", moduleId: 'course',    name: 'course'}
]);
```

The `studentId` parameter is optional.

Then I would look at how to use this course page to do everything you want based solely on the parameters it receives in the `activate` callback.

I don't have time to give a full answer right now, but hopefully this will help lead you down the right path!

Comment: Thanks, I see where you're going with this.  Feels a bit like a hack though.  I thought it would be easy to do with routers, but it seems routers in aurelia are quite basic.

Comment: Not sure what makes this a hack. It's a simple solution that doesn't create an unnecessarily complicated architecture. I could have shown you how to do this using design you have, but instead tried to help you see a different way to think about the problem. Another option is to use an optional parameter instead of two separate parameters.

Comment: In fact, I'm going to update my answer to use an optional parameter.

Comment: Yeah, maybe not a hack.  Just not the way I saw this working.  Thanks for your trouble.